# API data is not loading on Android Screen

Tags: java, android, api, android-recyclerview

I have been developing movie application which is a native android application using Java. So I am taking data from an API and displaying it on the screen but I am unable to see the Recycler View of the data on the screen.
I am using this API for getting Movies info:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FEND16/movie-json-data/master/json/top-rated-indian-movies-01.json

[image]

The above is the app UI I have to design for the purpose
I am not able to figure out where the code is getting broke.

MainActivity.java

```
...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String JSON_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FEND16/movie-json-data/master/json/top-rated-indian-movies-01.json";

    List<MovieModelClass> movieList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        movieList=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        //Creating a async task
        GetData getData=new GetData();
        getData.execute();
    }
    public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String current="";
            try{
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
                try{
                    url=new URL(JSON_URL);
                    urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream is=urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(is);
                    int data=isr.read();
                    while (data!=-1)
                    {
                        current+=(char)data;
                        data=isr.read();
                        return current;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    if(urlConnection!=null)
                    {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return current;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(s);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();++i)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    MovieModelClass model=new MovieModelClass();
                    model.setName(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                    model.setReleaseDate(jsonObject1.getString("year"));
                    model.setImg(jsonObject1.getString("poster"));

                    movieList.add(model);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            PutDataIntoRecyclerView(movieList);
        }
    }
    private void PutDataIntoRecyclerView(List<MovieModelClass> movieList){
        Adaptery adaptery =new Adaptery(this,movieList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptery);
    }
}
```

Adaptery.java

```
package patil.rohan.movieapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

public class Adaptery extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptery.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<MovieModelClass> mData;

    public Adaptery(Context mContext, List<MovieModelClass> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.release.setText(mData.get(position).getReleaseDate());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getImg()).into(holder.img);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
        TextView release;
        ImageView img;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
            release=itemView.findViewById(R.id.release_txt);
            img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }
    }
}
```

MovieModelClass.java

```
package patil.rohan.movieapplication;

public class MovieModelClass {
    String name;
    String releaseDate;
    String img;

    public MovieModelClass() {
    }

    public MovieModelClass(String name, String releaseDate, String img) {
        this.name = name;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

movie_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.809"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/release_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name_txt"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name_txt"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="95dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: check it data coming from api

Comment: Make sure you are getting data from API but not the exception. Set the debug point in your doInBackground method and onPostExecute method. Apart from that everything looks good.

Comment: `int data=isr.read();
                    while (data!=-1)
                    {
                        current+=(char)data;
                        data=isr.read();
                        return current;
                    }` You are doing nothing with the first byte you read. And then after the second byte read you return. So all you get in onPostExecute is one byte in the 'current' string.

Answer (score 0):

Call notifiyDatasetChanged() after

these lines

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptery);
```